# Spring Controller returns an empty object in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a spring controller that sends back a kotlin data class DTO, but no matter what I do it keeps returning an empty body.

```
data class ResponseDto(
        private val value1 : String?,
        private val value2 : String?,
        ....
        private val value5 : String?,
)
```

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when values in the data class are private. After leaving the controller, Spring turns the DTO into a response. Since it can't access the values in the DTO due to them being private, it returns an embty body.

Remove the private scoping from the data class values and everything should work as expected.

```
data class ResponseDto(
        val value1 : String?,
        val value2 : String?,
        ....
        val value5 : String?,
)
```

Comment: I'm using Java and I had a similar problem and the solution was the same. In my case, I added lombok @Getters annotation and it fixed the issue.